# Python put days from year in a list grouped by weeks

Tags: python, list, calendar

this is my actual code:

```
saptamani = []
        for months in range(1, 12):
            luna = calendar.monthcalendar(2020, months)
            for i in luna:
                prepare = [m for m in i if m > 0]
                if [prepare[0] != prepare[-1]]:
                    new_w = [prepare[0], prepare[-1]]
                saptamani.append(new_w)
```

Now my code print this:

```
[[1, 5], [6, 12], [13, 19], [20, 26], [27, 31], [1, 2], [3, 9], [10, 16], [17, 23], [24, 29], [1, 1], [2, 8], [9, 15], [16, 22], [23, 29], [30, 31], [1, 5], [6, 12], [13, 19], [20, 26], [27, 30], [1, 3], [4, 10],
[11, 17], [18, 24], [25, 31], [1, 7], [8, 14], [15, 21], [22, 28], [29, 30], [1, 5], [6, 12], [13, 19], [20, 26], [27, 31], [1, 2], [3, 9], [10, 16], [17, 23], [24, 30], [31, 31], [1, 6], [7, 13], [14, 20], [21, 2
7], [28, 30], [1, 4], [5, 11], [12, 18], [19, 25], [26, 31], [1, 1], [2, 8], [9, 15], [16, 22], [23, 29], [30, 30]]
```

What I wanted to do is to add the month number too, to be like this

```
[01.01, 05.01], [05.01, 12.01]....
```

Comment: `[01.01, 05.01]` is a list of floats, i assume you want strings? `['01.01', '05.01']`

Comment: @CoryKramer exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You think something like this perhaps?

```
saptamani = []
for months in range(1, 12):
    luna = calendar.monthcalendar(2020, months)
    for i in luna:
        prepare = [m for m in i if m > 0]
        if [prepare[0] != prepare[-1]]:
            new_w = ["{:02d}.{:02d}".format(prepare[0],months), "{:02d}.{:02d}".format(prepare[-1],months)]
        saptamani.append(new_w)
```

This writes saptamani variable like this:

```
[['01.01', '05.01'], ['06.01', '12.01'], ['13.01', '19.01'], ['20.01', '26.01'], ['27.01', '31.01'], ['01.02', '02.02'], ['03.02', '09.02'], ['10.02', '16.02'], ['17.02', '23.02'], ['24.02', '29.02'], ['01.03', '01.03'], ['02.03', '08.03'], ['09.03', '15.03'], ['16.03', '22.03'], ['23.03', '29.03'], ['30.03', '31.03'], ['01.04', '05.04'], ['06.04', '12.04'], ['13.04', '19.04'], ['20.04', '26.04'], ['27.04', '30.04'], ['01.05', '03.05'], ['04.05', '10.05'], ['11.05', '17.05'], ['18.05', '24.05'], ['25.05', '31.05'], ['01.06', '07.06'], ['08.06', '14.06'], ['15.06', '21.06'], ['22.06', '28.06'], ['29.06', '30.06'], ['01.07', '05.07'], ['06.07', '12.07'], ['13.07', '19.07'], ['20.07', '26.07'], ['27.07', '31.07'], ['01.08', '02.08'], ['03.08', '09.08'], ['10.08', '16.08'], ['17.08', '23.08'], ['24.08', '30.08'], ['31.08', '31.08'], ['01.09', '06.09'], ['07.09', '13.09'], ['14.09', '20.09'], ['21.09', '27.09'], ['28.09', '30.09'], ['01.10', '04.10'], ['05.10', '11.10'], ['12.10', '18.10'], ['19.10', '25.10'], ['26.10', '31.10'], ['01.11', '01.11'], ['02.11', '08.11'], ['09.11', '15.11'], ['16.11', '22.11'], ['23.11', '29.11'], ['30.11', '30.11']]
```

Your script wrote integer values but for getting something like "01.01" you need string instead.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need! Thanks mate!